# Axigen SMTP Server - ERROR: 454 Internal Error

Tags: smtp, email-server

We have a python script that sends mail via smtplib. On some specific users I receive `error 454`. User's email address does not exist on mail server side. From rfc of smtp it seems that negotiation is failed on first steps and mail server did not try to send any email whatsoever.

Our mail client logs:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 504, in data
    raise SMTPDataError(code, repl)
SMTPDataError: (454, 'Internal error')
```

The library code should help:

```
"""SMTP 'DATA' command -- sends message data to server.

Automatically quotes lines beginning with a period per rfc821.
Raises SMTPDataError if there is an unexpected reply to the
DATA command; the return value from this method is the final
response code received when the all data is sent.
"""
self.putcmd("data")
(code, repl) = self.getreply()
if self.debuglevel > 0:
    print>>stderr, "data:", (code, repl)
if code != 354:
    raise SMTPDataError(code, repl)  # THIS RAISE AN ERROR
else:
```

I know that code should be `354` for email to be sent. Is there anyone who could help on the error? I couldn't find any resource that could explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but by restarting the `Axigen` mail server the problem gone! :|

```
sudo /etc/init.d/axigen restart
```